# Can i revert back accidentally deleted Localized language in iTunesConnect account for an App?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

In my **iTunesConnect** I have uploaded latest build and it's localised in 10 languages.When I am submitting the app for review,it shows error to me on languages localisation.

**I just deleted accidentally by clicking on red (-) button. What should I need to do recover all of them (language)**.

Comment: if you know which languages were there you can add them again. Cannot revert them.

Comment: Did you delete one language or the build? Either way there is no "undo" in iTunes Connect. If you delete a language, you have to add it again and populate it manually.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not recover. You have to add again.